# WPF: Remove control's explicit foreground color

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

Two sample TextBoxes in a standard color scheme and the following constructor yield Box1 with a gray foreground and Box2 with a black foreground, since Box2's foreground color has been explicitly set.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Box2.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        Box1.IsEnabled = false;
        Box2.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

I would like to "unset" the foreground color so Box2 "falls back" to the default disabled color and has a gray foreground when IsEnabled is set to false. Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Setting the Foreground property to null does not have the desired effect. I want to avoid explicitly setting the Foreground color to Gray if possible, since it would not compatible with customized color schemes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you mean, but try following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Box2.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        Box1.IsEnabled = false;
        Box2.IsEnabled = false;
        Box2.ClearValue(TextBox.ForegroundProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, clearing the local value doesn't necessarily restore the same default. Reading about the ClearValue function, I discovered a discussion of the precedence here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.90).aspx and a sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771579(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the event IsEnabledChanged to set the foreground of the box.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Box2.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        Box1.IsEnabled = false;
        Box2.IsEnabled = false;
        Box1.IsEnabledChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(label1_IsEnabledChanged);
    }

    void label1_IsEnabledChanged( object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
        //Set the foreground you want here!
    }

}
```

But if you don't want to explicit set the color, try to set it to Transparent o.O

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Renanlf. However, I don't see how to use your answer without explicitly setting the foreground color in the event handler.

I want to avoid setting the foreground color explicitly if possible. I would like the foreground color of Box2 to "fall back" to the default disabled color. Do you know how to do this?

I tried using the Transparent brush, but that made all my text transparent.

Comment: What if you set a binding on the Foreground property, and in the set/get you do the logics to set the color acordding to the things you want?

Comment: What would I use in the setter/getter to make the foreground color fall back?